# Recursive method to construct self-dual codes

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory

I'm looking for the recursive methods of constructing self-dual binary codes. Recently, I found an interesting way to constructing such codes [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjwvKGltPHRAhWkKMAKHSFRD2MQFggzMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.bsu.az%2Fw24%2FV4N2%2Fpp177-186.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHDrvaK8_fo0o-wImBOKF2ZIOdpXw&sig2=bioeWatJ6kcBjC9jlVek_Q). In this method, by using $[2n,n,d]$ self-dual code, we can construct the $[2(n+1),n+1,d']$ self-dual code. I constructed thousands of these binary self-dual codes, but I saw that $d' \leq d$.

Now my question is:

> Can we find some codes with this method such that $d'>d$?
>
> Or, Are there exist another methods to construct $[2(n+1),n+1,d']$ self-dual code from $[2n,n,d]$ self-dual code such away that $d'>d$?

Comment: Just a comment, Patrick Sole might be a good person to email and ask.

Comment: @kodlu, Thanks for your comment. I asked him.